# Can thousands of objects hurt performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

Case in point is how **RoBrowser** handles each incoming/outgoing packet.

First off, **RoBrowser** uses classes for each packet, there are thousands of packets and they will be instantiated every time they are received or sent.

The packets are defined [here](https://github.com/vthibault/roBrowser/blob/master/src/Network/PacketStructure.js#L2681). Let us take `#L2681` as an example:

```
// 0x204
PACKET.CA.EXE_HASHCHECK = function PACKET_CA_EXE_HASHCHECK() {
    this.HashValue  = '';

    this.build = function() {
        var pkt_len = 2 + 16;
        var pkt_buf = new BinaryWriter(pkt_len);

        pkt_buf.writeShort(0x204);
        pkt_buf.writeBinaryString(this.HashValue, 16);
        return pkt_buf;
    };
};
```

We can find that packet being instantiated [here](https://github.com/vthibault/roBrowser/blob/master/src/Engine/LoginEngine.js#L244).

```
pkt           = new PACKET.CA.EXE_HASHCHECK();
pkt.HashValue = hash;
Network.sendPacket(pkt);
```

Though this is a packet that is only sent once, imagine if this was a packet that is sent thousand times like a `Walk` or `Attack` packet.

I am no expert in programming, oop or javascript but I have read a thing or two.

Notes:

- Unlike RoBrowser which is written for the browser, my server will be written in node.js, purely server side.
- **RoBrowser** is client side so it only handles its request from 1 server. While in my case, it'll handle all connected clients.

Questions:

- Is **RoBrowser's** way of handling packets slow for a server architecture?
- Is there a huge difference in performance between using classes and not?

> I'm looking for references on this topic (packet handling). If you know any, please do tell.

Comment: Depends... What is a `class`? If you keep it small, it won't be significantly slower. If you inject your whole environment into a single class, it's BIG. Why don't you simply do some benchmark and create 1kk objects and 1kk variables and test the performance with simple functions ?

Answer (score 1):

Defining object methods this way would create new functions for every instantiated object - bad for many objects :-(

With the prototype-way, only one method is created on the prototype object, that is shared by all instances:

```
// 0x204
PACKET.CA.EXE_HASHCHECK = function PACKET_CA_EXE_HASHCHECK() {
 this.HashValue  = '';
};

PACKET_CA_EXE_HASHCHECK.prototype.build = function() {
    var pkt_len = 2 + 16;
    var pkt_buf = new BinaryWriter(pkt_len);

    pkt_buf.writeShort(0x204);
    pkt_buf.writeBinaryString(this.HashValue, 16);
    return pkt_buf;
};
```